# React, iterating keys with conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

My question is regarding iteration of keys. I want the id with className `greenButton` to be applied to the id with className `yellowButton` onClick. The problem is that the ´yellowButton´s id is always lagging behind one eventhough they access the same variable.

TL;DR

`buttonId` is x where className = `greenButton` and x-1 where className = `yellowButton` how do I fix this?

```
 const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 1;
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((time, i) => {
          let buttonId = id++;
          if (myBookings().result.includes(id)) {
            return (
              <button
                id={buttonId}
                className="yellowButton"
                onClick={() => cancelBooking()}
              >
                {time} {console.log({ buttonId }, { id })} // buttonId is 1 & id is 2
              </button>
            );
          } else if (occupiedSlots().result.includes(id)) {
            return (
              <button id={buttonId} className="redButton">
                {time}
              </button>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <button
                id={buttonId}
                className="greenButton"
                onClick={() => {
                  BookSlot({ id: buttonId });
                  console.log({ buttonId }); // is 2
                }}
              >
                {time}
                {buttonId}
              </button>
            );
          }
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
};
```

Comment: I think `let buttonId = id++;` is what causing you the problem. Try using `let buttonId = ++id;` instead maybe?

Comment: That did it! what´s the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `let buttonId = id++;` is what causing you this problem. Try using `let buttonId = ++id;` (pre-increment instead of post-increment).

This is what I read somewhere and might answer your question: "preincrement (++i) adds one to the value of i, then returns i; in contrast, i++ returns i then adds one to it, which in theory results in the creation of a temporary variable storing the value of i before the increment operation was applied".

More reading can be found [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/difference-between-postfix-and-prefix-increment-in-javascript/)